# How change date of object of NSSet

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, ios7.1, nsset

I have this core data model.I have a student and the student has parents (NSSet parent) and the parents has a few attribute and also attribute addressHome and addressEmployer (address is also object so they have two simple objects - addressHome and addressEmployer - not NSSet). Now, I need change the parent. I use this code for change parents attributes, but works very strange. Sometimes save only general data of mother and father, sometimes also a both address of mother, but never any address of father. I dont understand it... I tried debug and the textFields are filled right, so there isnt a problem. Could you advise me please? Here is the simple code of adding new student.

```
// add new student
if(!self.selectedStudentID){
    Student *student = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Student" inManagedObjectContext:cdh.context];

    // student hasnt parents --> create new
    if(student.parents.count == 0){
        Parent *mother = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Parent" inManagedObjectContext:cdh.context];
        mother.type = @"mother";
        [student addParentsObject:mother];

        Parent *father = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Parent" inManagedObjectContext:cdh.context];
        father.type = @"father";
        [student addParentsObject:father];
    }


    for (Parent *parent in student.parents) {
        // mother
        if([parent.type isEqualToString:@"mother"]){

            parent.name = motherVC.motherNameTextField.text;
            parent.job = motherVC.motherJobTextField.text;
            parent.phone = motherVC.motherPhoneHomeTextView.text;
            parent.phoneWork = motherVC.motherPhoneWorkTextView.text;

            // creating an AddressHome
            if(!parent.addressHome){
                Address *addressMotherHome = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Address" inManagedObjectContext:cdh.context];
                parent.addressHome = addressMotherHome;
            }

            // assign values
            parent.addressHome.city = motherVC.motherAddressCityTextField.text;
            parent.addressHome.street = motherVC.motherAddressStreetTextField.text;
            parent.addressHome.postcode = motherVC.motherAddressPostCodeTextField.text;
            parent.addressHome.houseNumber = motherVC.motherAddressHouseNumberTextField.text;

            // Creating an AddressEmployer
            if(!parent.addressEmployer){
                Address *addressMotherEmployer = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Address" inManagedObjectContext:cdh.context];
                parent.addressEmployer = addressMotherEmployer;
            }

            // assign values
            parent.addressEmployer.city = motherVC.motherEmployerAddressCityTextField.text;
            parent.addressEmployer.street = motherVC.motherEmployerAddressStreetTextField.text;
            parent.addressEmployer.postcode = motherVC.motherEmployerAddressPostCodeTextField.text;
            parent.addressEmployer.houseNumber = motherVC.motherEmployerAddressHouseNumberTextField.text;

            [cdh saveContext];
        }

        // father
        else if([parent.type isEqualToString:@"father"]){

            parent.name = fatherVC.fatherNameTextField.text;
            parent.job = fatherVC.fatherJobTextField.text;
            parent.phone = fatherVC.fatherPhoneHomeTextView.text;
            parent.phoneWork = fatherVC.fatherPhoneWorkTextView.text;

            // creating addressHome
            if(!parent.addressHome){
                Address *addressFatherHome = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Address" inManagedObjectContext:cdh.context];
                parent.addressHome = addressFatherHome;
            }

            // assign values
            parent.addressHome.city = fatherVC.fatherAddressCityTextField.text;
            parent.addressHome.street = fatherVC.fatherAddressStreetTextField.text;
            parent.addressHome.postcode = fatherVC.fatherAddressPostCodeTextField.text;
            parent.addressHome.houseNumber = fatherVC.fatherAddressHouseNumberTextField.text;

            // creating address-employer
            if(!parent.addressEmployer){
                Address *addressFatherEmployer = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Address" inManagedObjectContext:cdh.context];
                parent.addressEmployer = addressFatherEmployer;
            }

            // assign values
            parent.addressEmployer.city = fatherVC.fatherEmployerAddressCityTextField.text;
            parent.addressEmployer.street = fatherVC.fatherEmployerAddressStreetTextField.text;
            parent.addressEmployer.postcode = fatherVC.fatherEmployerAddressPostCodeTextField.text;
            parent.addressEmployer.houseNumber = fatherVC.fatherEmployerAddressHouseNumberTextField.text;

            [cdh saveContext];
        }
    }

    // assign values for student
    student.name = studentVC.studentNameTextField.text;
    student.birthNumber = studentVC.studentBirthNumberTextField.text;
    student.birthplace = studentVC.studentBirthPlaceTextField.text;
    student.identityCard = studentVC.studentIdentityCardTextField.text;
    student.nationality = studentVC.studentNationalityTextField.text;
    student.legalRepresentative = studentVC.studentLegalRepresentativeTextField.text;
    student.entranceToSchool = studentVC.studentEntranceToSchoolTextField.text;
    student.otherSchool = studentVC.studentOtherSchoolTextField.text;
    student.phone = studentVC.studentPhoneTextField.text;
    student.email = studentVC.studentEmailTextField.text;
    student.healthInsurer = studentVC.studentHealthInsurerTextField.text;
    student.codeOfHealthInsurer = studentVC.studentCodeOfHealthInsurerTextField.text;
    student.healthProblem = studentVC.studentHealthProblemTextView.text;
    student.releaseFromGym = studentVC.studentReleaseFromGymTextView.text;

    [cdh saveContext];

    // end of new student
}
```

Comment: I don't see "date" anywhere in your question text.

Comment: I also don't see an NSSet declared anywhere.